# RIA Services: Unable to find metadata for 'Entities'

Tags: silverlight, wcf-ria-services

Using RIA Services for a Silverlight/ASP.net project.  I am trying to follow the steps defined here:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896240.aspx
to pre-generate the Entity views, which will help startup time of the Entity Model.  Once I set Metadata Artifact Processing to 'Copy to Output Directory' in my entity model project, I start getting the error:  Unable to find metadata for 'Entities' in the Silverlight project.

Is pre-generating views a supported feature with RIA Services?

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue when importing the EDMX file from an existing solution and changing the namespace.

I solved it by changing all the existing namespace references including in the domainmodel.Designer.cs and changing the name of the contex to a different name and then rebuilding the web project then the SL project.  (requires you to change your usings also)

Afterwards you can change it back to its original name.

You can tell if you have the same issue that I did by seeing if you have a generated code folder (hidden) in the SL project.